# Convert serialized string that contains &, = to Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#submit-form').click(function(){
    var data_serialize = $("#form").serialize();
    $("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").each(function(e){ 
          data_serialize += "&"+this.name+'=0';
    });
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(e){ 
          data_serialize += "&"+this.name+'=1';
    });
    console.log(data_serialize);
})
```

The above code gives me a string

```
companyName=&contactName=&role=&email=&phone=&desctiption=&websiteURL=&tc-check=0
```

like this. How can I make it as an Object?

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"' + 'YOURSTRING'.replace(/=/g,'":"').replace(/&/g, '","') + '"}');`

Comment: @Shubham Thanks. Its working. I understood the logic. But, I searched for the predefined method. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 2):

It will convert this string to an javascript object.

```js
var yourString = 'companyName=&contactName=&role=&email=&phone=&desctiption=&websiteURL=&tc-check=0';


var yourObj = JSON.parse('{"' + yourString.replace(/=/g,'":"').replace(/&/g, '","') + '"}');


console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObj));
```

Comment: @Mr_Perfect - I don't think there is a predefined function for this thing in javascript. Even you can't get data from the URL directly in javascript

Comment: Seems awfully fragile to me.

Comment: Hey there is a problem with this. If I enter value with white space it is giving like, companyName="Hello%Stackoverflow", Unable to replace it. Can you please do that? If I replace with space, the output contains 20 instead of space

Comment: @Mr_Perfect- Is it %20 or just percent? I don't think only % will come.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake

Comment: Use `decodeURIComponent(yourString)` and then perform the other operations

Answer (score 1):

You can easily loop through the form controls building an object via brackets notation:

```
$('#submit-form').click(function(){
    var obj = {};
    $("#form").find("input, textarea, select").each(function() {
        var type = this.type.toLowerCase();
        if (this.name && !this.disabled && type !== "button" && type !== "submit") {
            if (type === "checkbox") {
                obj[this.name] = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
            } else {
                obj[this.name] = $(this).val();
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Note that we skip disabled inputs and inputs without names, as that's the standard for forms (it's what HTML does, and what `serialize` does). The above preserves your non-standard handling of checkboxes.

Example:

```js
$('#submit-form').click(function(){
    var obj = {};
    $("#form").find("input, textarea, select").each(function() {
        var type = this.type.toLowerCase();
        if (this.name && !this.disabled && type !== "button" && type !== "submit") {
            if (type === "checkbox") {
                obj[this.name] = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
            } else {
                obj[this.name] = $(this).val();
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input name="btn" type="button" value="Buttons are ignored">
  <input name="text1" type="text" value="text here">
  <input name="cb1" type="checkbox" checked>
  <input name="cb2" type="checkbox">
  <select name="s1">
    <option value="foo" selected>foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
  </select>
  <textarea name="ta">testing</textarea>
  <input name="text-disabled" type="text" disabled value="don't include me">
  <input type="text" value="Ignore me I don't have a name">
  <input type="button" id="submit-form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Mr_Perfect: There will be a loop somewhere, why not in this code?